# WindowsPhone 8 listboxitem has a max height limit?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, listboxitem

This problem bothre me so long. In the Page,I use a listbox to show a listdata ,and the item datatemplate is

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="PostItem">
    <Grid Width="460" Margin="0,2,0,2">
            <control:RichTextControl Segments="{Binding ListSegment, Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="25">
                <control:RichTextControl.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="control:RichTextControl">
                    <StackPanel Name="RootStackPanel" CacheMode="BitmapCache" Background="{StaticResource BlockBackground}"  />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </control:RichTextControl.Template>
            </control:RichTextControl>
        </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

And the stackpanel RootStackPanel is a  usercontrol,i add  a mount of textblock in it.when the amont is too large,it can show the Backgruond as you see: when the item is too high to display the bacground.while the short item can display as i except.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the attribute horizontal alignment to stretch like this:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle> 
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem"> 
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter> 
    </Style> 
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: It doen't work.And i  track the very high listboxitem,it have the rightbackgruond color,but i really doen't show as except.